# Facebook permission dialogue not showing in app?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, facebook-ios-sdk

Permission dialogue not showing in my app if user has configured Facebook account with their phone?

[image]

Can anybody help me what was missing by me?

Here is my code

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
        self.loginButton.readPermissions=@[@"public_profile",@"email",@"user_likes",@"user_about_‌​me",@"user_hometown",@"user_location"];

self.loginButton.delegate=self;
}
       // enter code 

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{
        NSLog(@"login %@",loginView);
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
        NSLog(@"%@", user);
}

       // enter

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView
{ 
        NSLog(@"logout  %@",loginView);
}
```

Comment: http://pastie.org/9373660#9,13,18

Comment: Edit your question and add the code block with proper formatting in it. Avoid using paste-bins when you're posting on Stack Overflow. (:

Comment: @Neeku plz see see my editable code and help me.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether you done followings

1. open `developer.facebook.com`
2. go to projects which you have created
3. go to settings --> go to add platform--> select iOS
4. In that use bundle ID which is similar to your project bundle ID and hit save
5. status and Review and make sure your app is on (In settings you have your mail ID correctly)

Comment: thank you for replying and yes i had followed all steps which is suggest by you. In fact app is working properly if user do not configured Facebook account with their iphone. my problem is when user tapped on login button and he is already configured his/her account then how can i get their name?